# How to check in ssis if record already exists

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How to check in SSIS if particular record(primary key column) is already exists in a destination table, update if it is present else insert it.

I gone through searching on net for several hours but could not find exact solution. Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some examples from the internet:
[Anatomy of incremental load](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/07/09/ssis-design-pattern-incremental-loads.aspx)

[Another example](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/76390/)

These should give you detailed examples.

Comment: Great work Samuel Vanga. Thanks a lot for providing this. First links is very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative - a lot less code and runs very quickly.

First load a Lookup Cache using a Cache Transform with any of the columns you want to preserve (at a minimum, the surrogate key and business key) from the target table. Then truncate the target table. Then at the end of your main Data Flow, add a Lookup using the Cache, joined on your Business Key, and return all the columns you want to preserve. Match Output goes to an OLE DB Destination with Keep identity checked (to preserve your Surrogate Keys). No Match Output goes to a separate OLE DB Destination. Both destinations must have Table lock unchecked (to avoid deadlocks), but can use fast load.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to check records is available in Destination using lookup transformation. If receive records is not matched with existing data then it's new records else it's old.